# MYSQL DATE_FORMAT Conversion

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need to convert `19/06/2021 21:06:55` to a MySQL date format. I tried

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("19/06/2021 21:06:55", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") as reg_date FROM users
```

but am getting an error? What path should I follow to achieve this?

It should be like this:

```
2021-06-19 21:06:55
```

Comment: What is the error? Where is the string? How do PHP/mysqli relate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATE_FORMAT` formats ISO dates to other formats, but what you have is not an ISO date.
Use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert the string to a date which is already in the format that you want:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('19/06/2021 21:06:55', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS reg_date FROM users
```

Comment: This is a great solution, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("19/06/2021 21:06:55", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s") as reg_date
```

Which returns '2021-06-19 21:06:55'